# Installation error in sphinx search

Tags: sphinx

While installing sphnix,
I followed the steps mentioned in this  [link](http://paulscott.co.za/blog/imported-title-48/)

I get errors after i give the command `Make`

*"All docs are already pre-built by developer. If you want to rebuild them, install docbook-xsl and xsltproc and then run 'make docs' instead of simple 'make' ".*

Please help me with this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's NOT an error, it's just a note, telling you the docs haven't been rebuilt.